# Do error bars give information about the dispersion of the raw data from the study?

Tags: dataset, standard-error, error

Do error bars give information about the dispersion of the raw data from the study? If data in a graph has standard error bars will this provide information about the dispersion of the raw data obtained in the study?

Answer (score 4):

No, it won't. A standard error measures theoretical variation for the particular estimator at the given sample size. The standard error doesn't describe variability in the individual data points; you would need to use the standard deviation to show inter-observation variability in a sample.

Further, if the sample size for the specific sample statistic and standard error are included, you could back out the standard deviation depending on how the standard error is related to the standard deviation (i.e. if it's the standard error of the mean, you would be able to multiply the standard error by the square root of the respective sample size to return the sample standard deviation). Although, as said by Nick Cox, showing the raw data would be the easiest and clearest way to show variability of the individual values.